# How do I properly pass through a parameter using .addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm building a registration form with alphabetical input only, and I'm trying to simplify my code so that if a non-alphabetical character is entered into either `fname` or `lname`, it'd output the error message below.

Currently, the error message appears prior to inputting and remains even when I input alphabetical characters. My guess is that I get the error message before inputting anything because the `addEventListener` function immediately calls `fname` or `lname` with no input (thus the subsequent error), but why doesn't this resolve itself once you fill in the inputs with alphabetical characters?

I know how to code this with two different `ABCvalidate` functions (i.e. removing the parameters and using `fname.value` and `lname.value`, respectively, but I'm looking for a simplistic solution that works within one `ABCvalidate` function.

```
// First Name & Last Name Validation

let ABC = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

let fname = document.getElementById("fname");
fname.addEventListener('input', ABCvalidate(fname));
let lname = document.getElementById("lname");
lname.addEventListener('input', ABCvalidate(lname));

function ABCvalidate(name) {
  const errorElement = document.getElementById("CSerror");
  if (!ABC.test(name.value)) {
    errorElement.innerHTML =
      "No spaces, numbers, or special characters allowed";
  } else {
    errorElement.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

[image: 2][image: 1]

Comment: addEventListener second argument needs to be a function, not the result of calling a function - you could do `() => ABCvalidate(fname)` instead of `ABCvalidate(fname)`

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://kooi.dev/showFiddle/k8nLrsve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use anonymous functions:

**Variant A**

```
let fname = document.getElementById("fname");
let lname = document.getElementById("lname");

fname.addEventListener('input', function() {
    ABCvalidate(this);
});

lname.addEventListener('input', function() {
    ABCvalidate(this);
});
```

Instead of using `fname` and `lname` as parameter, you can just use `this` in this context as this will refer back to the element the event listener was added to.

**Variant B**

The so-called [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?retiredLocale=de) user Jaromanda X already mentioned is also possible. You can't use the `this` keyword, but you can - as slebetman mentioned - pass `event` and therefore use `event.target` instead:

```
let fname = document.getElementById("fname");
let lname = document.getElementById("lname");

fname.addEventListener('input', (event) => ABCvalidate(event.target));
lname.addEventListener('input', (event) => ABCvalidate(event.target));
```

Comment: IMHO the replacement of `this` is `event.target`: `fname.addEventListener('input',(e) => ABCvalidate(e.target))`